# How does a GPS receiver synchronize its quartz clock with GPS satellites?

Tags: algorithm, gps

I read a lot of tutorials and articles on **How GPS works** and found that it works on the principle of **3d Trilateration**. GPS receivers have normally an ordinary quartz clock and GPS satellites have very costly atomic clock who have very high precision.

In one article it was mentioned that as ordinary quartz clock in GPS receivers have very less accuracy but they periodically reset their clock with GPS satellites clocks. And if both GPS receiver and GPS satellites clocks are synchronized then only GPS receiver can calculate its accurate distance from a GPS satellite.

How does a GPS receiver synchronize its clock with GPS satellites? This I tried to find out from many articles and many calculations, but I could not reach any solution. Could anyone please explain how a normal quartz clock at GPS receiver gets sync with GPS satellites?

Comment: Why was this closed as off-topic? Sync'ing clocks is a programming problem -- can you tell me how a GPS receiver would discipline its clock without a micro-processor and software?

Comment: See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face".  This question requires way too much speculation to be practically answerable with any degree of accuracy.  E.g. I can easily imagine a GPS sync implemented fully in hardware.

Comment: The reality is they aren't implemented fully in hardware -- the algorithms are too complicated. e.g., lookup GPS T-RAIM -- embedded micro-processors are used for these tasks.

Comment: It seems to me that clock synchronization is a practical problem, and the answer doesn't require much speculation at all -- the problem is *not* too hard to practically answer, because we are surrounded by technology that implements these algorithms -- in *software*!

Comment: @AnthonyBlake: Vote to reopen then.  I voted to close because I figured the OP wasn't actually trying to write this software.  But I'd vote to reopen if you feel strongly about it, and someone can give an authoritative answer on how to write the algorithm for doing it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programming.  Can you please explain in your question how this is related to programming, so that it doesn't keep getting closed?

Comment: A GPS device doesn't use its own clock at all, because it is nowhere near precise enough. Instead it measures how much different the signals from four satellites are. It doesn't say "I'm x, y and z nanoseconds away from three satellites A, B and C, so I calculate I must be here". It says "I'm x nanoseconds closer to satellite A than B, y nanoseconds closer to A than C, z nanoseconds closer to A than D" and calculates the position from that. No clock needed in the GPS device. But you need four satellites, not three.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crystal itself isn't a clock -- a crystal and a counter implement the clock. The counter might represent time with 32-bits for seconds and 32-bits for fractions of a second.

Every clock cycle, the counter is incremented with another value that represents the fractions of a second that passes per clock cycle.

So the clock can be sped up/slowed down by increasing/decreasing the amount of time that is added to the counter every clock cycle.

Relative to some master clocks, your clock will have frequency and phase differences -- usually you have some logic in a small micro-processor that measure these differences and slowly alters your clock to match the master clock -- using the value added to the counter every clock cycle.

To sum it up with an answer: the clock in your GPS receiver (crystal + counter) is sync'ed with the GPS satellite using algorithms called phase locked loops (PLL) and frequency locked loops (FLL).

### Phase Mismatch

Phase sync is required because you can have two clocks that are running at the same speed, yet one is ahead of the other. e.g., clock A reads 31337.000000001 seconds and clock B reads 31337.000000002 seconds. One second later, clock A reads 31338.000000001 and clock B reads 31338.000000002 -- both clocks have progressed one second in time, but one clock is still ahead by 1 nanosecond. i.e., clock B is 2*pi*10^(-9) radians/sec out of phase with respect to clock A

### Frequency Mismatch

Frequency sync is required because one clock can be running faster than the other. e.g., clock A reads 31337 seconds, and clock B reads 31337 seconds, but one second later, clock A reads 31338 seconds and clock B reads 31338.000000001 seconds -- clock B has run faster than clock A by 1 nanosecond/second.

### In practice

In practice you have to account for both of these problems in order to sync one clock to a master clock, because no oscillators are totally precise and stable. So what GPS does is give the clock long term discipline through the use of FLL and PLL algorithms -- the quartz oscillator in the GPS is still relatively unstable compared to a TCXO or atomic oscillator, but at least it can be disciplined to be long term precise.

Comment: PLL seems useful for getting two signals in phase sync, but I don't know how necessary phase sync is.  It seems that seconds-sync is more important, which I'm not sure (from the brief skimming of the wiki article and my brief experience in hobbiest electronics) that PLL would solve.  I'm no expert on GPS though, and why the clocks even have to be in sync.  Can you explain some of these things in your answer?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Sure, see above.

Comment: +1; This is a good description of what the algorithms accomplish, but I don't know if this level of accuracy is important for the calculation.  The OP didn't mention *how* accurate the sync has to be.  You seem to imply that it needs to be processor-clock-tick accurate, but I doubt that.  I think it would be nearly impossible to achieve to that level of accuracy due to the nature of the communication channel between the satellite and the GPS.  I'm just casting a critical eye, though.  I don't know GPSs :)

Comment: Well, GPS aren't only used for determining location -- there are many GPS'es that are designed to be fixed in one position on a roof for timekeeping purposes. E.g., The Trimble Thunderbolts have UTC +/- 15 nanosecond accuracy for 1PPS signals. That level of accuracy is very important for many applications, such as cell phone base stations, high-frequency trading, multi-point high-throughput network capture etc

Comment: Also, I don't know much about this, but apparently it is quite common that there aren't enough satellites in position to obtain a good enough estimate of position for systems such as in auto-pilot landings for aircraft -- even in the continental US, for periods of a few hours or so in a certain area. In these situations it is advantageous to have a better clock in the GPS -- one that implements T-RAIM.

Comment: This explains how the clocks are synchronized technically, but the better question is how the correct time is calculated with which to synchronize. Because the system relies on calculating the difference between the time the signal was sent and received, we can't use the time the signal was sent to match with the internal quartz clock or ∆T would be zero. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

A common way of syncing clocks over latent networks (you could consider a satellite linkup a "latent network") is the [Network Time Protocol](http://www.ntp.org/).  The protocol was designed for a very similar purpose - syncing less stable clocks with atomic clocks.

The NTP probably will deal with more issues than a GPS would, but studying the design of NTP could give you a thorough understanding of how to sync two clocks when you can't determine the latency with 100% accuracy.  I.e. when you can't simply measure a wire length, latency of electronic components, and number of system clock cycles involved in the process.

Comment: Why the downvote, anonymous downvoter?  I admit my answer isn't directly applicable in itself (you wouldn't simply run an NTP client on the GPS receiver and call it done).  But as far as I can tell the OP is looking for knowledge of how things work, not how to implement a solution to a problem they actually face.  I imagine NTP is a more generalized solution to the same problem than whatever hacks are separately programmed into the firmware of each and every separate model of GPS...